# Pause-Continue reading large text file with php

Tags: php, text

I have the below PHP code. I want to be able to continue reading the text file from the point it stopped, and the text file is over 90mb.

Is it possible to continue reading from the point the script stopped running?

```
$in = fopen('email.txt','r');

while($kw = trim(fgets($in))) {
    //my code
}
```

Comment: This gets to the crux of the matter: If you want to build functionality, you have to deal with it as a problem to solve. Is it possible? Yes. Is there a prebuilt solution? Probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not easily possible without saving the current state from time to time.

However, instead of doing that you should better try to fix whatever causes your script to stop. `set_time_limit(0);` and `ignore_user_abort(true);` will most likely prevent your script from being stopped while it's running.

If you *do* want to be able to continue from some position, use `ftell($in)` to get the position and store it in a file/database from time to time. When starting the script you check if you have a stored position and then simply `fseek($in, $offset);` after opening the file.

If the script is executed from a browser and it takes enough time to make aborts likely, you could also consider splitting it in chunks and cleanly terminating the script with a redirect containing an argument where to continue. So your script would process e.g. 1000 lines and then be restarted with an offset of 1000 to process the next 1000 lines and so on.

Comment: Splitting pages into "views" is a pretty well-known "problem" IMO. Hence, it's "easily possible" as long as you have an approach, and the web proliferates with approaches. See time.com, thedailybeast.com, etc. It's all in the approach.

Comment: I don't think he is looking for pagination.

Comment: The OP's "approach" is not pagination, but the solution is, or at least involves understanding where the reader left off in a "page" sense.

Comment: @ThiefMaster the script stop because exceeds the time limit. I use a shared server online and i can't increase the limits. I want to run it as a cron job every half/hour  . Is it possible to give me an example on how to use ftell using a file to be able to continue it? Actually i liked your idea to splitting it in chunks but i don't how to do it....thank you!